# Sending an sms intent to the Messaging app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sms, smsmanager

The objective of my application is to filter `SMS's` received on the basis of some parameters and depending on the validity of those to either drop or accept the `SMS`.

I became aware that it's no longer possible (since `Android KitKat`) to have a stealth app that does this, therefore I decided to make it the default app.

I am currently having a lot of trouble sending an intent (received through the `onReceive` function in my app, through a `BroadcastReceiver`) to the stock `SMS` app (This would allow for only certain `SMS` to be received).

I found out that using this piece of code:

```
Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(getApplicationContext());
```

I was able to obtain the used packaged `(com.android.mms)` for the stock SMS app. And through some researching I found out that `transaction.SmsReceiver` was the class I was looking for.

However, I'm now having trouble sending the intent to this specific app.

```
Intent redirectIntent = intent;
redirectIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms.transaction","com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiver");
redirectIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(redirectIntent);
```

I obtain the following error:

```
W/System.err: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.mms.transaction/com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiver};
```

Comment: First, you don't use `startActivity()` to send a broadcast to a `BroadcastReceiver`. Second, you can't do what you're trying to do. If you're the default, you handle everything. You can't just pass off the functions you don't want to code.

Comment: @MikeM. So there's no way possible to circumvent this? Ultimately the only thing I want to do is act as a sort of vault for SMS's deriving from certain numbers and for this reason I must not let them reach the normal inbox.

Comment: Nope. There really isn't any such thing as a dedicated SMS blocker anymore, since KitKat. Only the default can block, but if you're the default, you're responsible for a lot of stuff, including sending and receiving both SMS and MMS, handling their storage in the Provider, etc.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.putExtra("address", "12125551212");
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","Body of Message");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```